# Orgmode export html with fontawesome characters

Tags: org-export, html

I have an org document in which I inserted fontawesome characters (with the package [fontawesome](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-fontawesome/)).

When exporting to html, the characters are exported as is instead of being exported in html fontawesome code. For instance,
`` should get exported as:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

I guess I could achieve this with some post-export hook. How would I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can define your own [special symbols](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) by customizing `org-entities-user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@@html:...@@`, for example:

`@@html:<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>@@`

ref: [Quoting HTML tags](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html#Quoting-HTML-tags)

Comment: This is more portable, I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks juancho's comment, I came out with a nice setting to set this up.

You can set org-entities-user like this for example.

```
'(org-entities-user
   (quote
     (("faCogs" "\\faCogs" nil "<i class=\"fa fa-cogs\"></i>" "=cogs=" "=cogs=" "")
     ("faPlus" "\\faPlus" nil "<i class=\"fa fa-plus\"></i>" "+" "+" ""))))
```

```

The "tofus" are the symbols in fontawesome.

In my orgmode document, I just need to do `\faCogs`, and with `M-x org-toggle-pretty-entities`, the fontawesome symbol appears.